# Why are file objects their own iterators in python?

Tags: python, file, python-3.x

I am learning python and this thing is confusing me.
Wouldn't it be better if file iterator and file object were different , this way we can support multiple iteration in files.
So why are python file objects their own iterators ?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "multiple iteration in files"?

Comment: @61612: `iter(fileobj)` then iterate over that, and it'll be independent from another `iter(fileobj)`.

Comment: That is what `file.seek` allows you to do .

Comment: I/O is a typical bottleneck, so reading a file multiple times is almost never a good idea.

Comment: Because a single instance of a file object can't generally be iterated over by different iterators at the same time.

Comment: @Martijn: except that the two iterators will interact and likely mess-up each others state.

Comment: @martineau: if you open a file twice for reading (two Python `open()` calls) things just work. Nothing messes up those file handles.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with "multiple iteration"?  Could you provide a code example using this technique?  If you mean that you want nested loops or some such, you could always load the data to iterate over into memory (perhaps into a list), and then process it however you need to.  Re-reading the same parts of a file is unnecessary and slow, though I believe you can have multiple read-only file handles open if you really want to.

Comment: One could build an iterator around [`os.pread`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.pread) which would permit multiple instances per file. Most useful if file descriptors are limited.

Comment: @Martijn: `iter(fileobj)` doesn't appearing to be opening a file. Maybe `iter(open(filename))`...

Comment: @martineau: when I talked about `iter(fileobj)` I meant that that's how the OP would *like* it to work. It certainly doesn't work like that now, no.

Comment: Maybe you should take a look on itertools.tee - which duplicates iterators using a smart as it can be cache between them - so if you have an algorithm in which you need to check the previous "m" lines behind a main iterator "i", you could just "tee" the file iterator, and would spare memory.

Usually, reading all the file into memory will be easier and not a problem for most workloads, thought.

Comment: So why cant the feature of multiple iterator (like lists ) be added for files ? what is the problem in that ?

Answer (score 4):

Because your OS doesn't let you do this and because disk files are not the [only type of I/O](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_file_types) Python file objects support. Files are *streams* of data and handled a lot like other stream sources such as sockets and pipes.

Streams behave exactly like iterators, except a disk file can also support seeking. Network sockets and pipes on the other hand don't support seeking, but to the OS and to Python those are also streams or files.

This abstraction makes it possible to apply a lot of optimisations to file (and stream) handling and has been the de-facto way of looking at files for decades now.

Python *could* handle disk file objects differently and open up multiple OS file handles for a given Python file object. But that would be rather inefficient; the bottleneck is the communication with the disk, and although your OS can buffer data as it comes from the hard disk, you should generally *avoid* reading from the same file more than once.

On top of this there are the issues with *writing* to the disk. The OS already requires you to specify a file mode; reading or writing. You can open a file handle that can do both, but then the OS may have to handle caching in a different way, as it needs to take into account that your file may have been altered when you read the same bits again. Python would have to replicate all this if it were to allow for multiple iterators, where you are also writing to the stream.

Comment: you could have reduced this to "Because someone said so a long time ago." (+1 all the same :P)

Comment: I didn't really understand , why cant file object and file iterator be two different things so that we can call iter(file object) to create multiple file iterators just like lists ?

Comment: @ShikharSrivastava: because not all file objects support seeking or multiple iterators, and because supporting that use case would encourage inefficient file handling. Read once as you process, avoid reading multiple times.

Comment: @ShikharSrivastava: note that file objects are also returned for pipes and for sockets, for example. You cannot put multiple iterators on those because the computer *doesn't have the data to seek over*.

Comment: Why this kind of distinction between lists and files ? Why is this not supported in files but in lists ?

Comment: @ShikharSrivastava: Files are not lists. Files are like generators in Python, you don't necessarily know what is going to come next as you iterate.

Comment: @ShikharSrivastava: A list object fits in memory in one go, Python has full control over it and can see all elements at any given time. You have *full random access*. Not all files provide full random access.

Comment: @ShikharSrivastava If you want files to behave ”like lists” for iteration, then you shoudl read them completely into memory, e.g. `fileContents = fileObj.readlines()`. Then, you can have independent iterators on the `fileContents`. But you will be reading the whole file into the memory which very often is not desired when reading files (not reading everything into memory is actually a huge point about iterators).

Comment: @MartinpPeters I still didn't get you. Can you explain this in simple language ? Why multiple iterators are not supported for files ?

Comment: @ShikharSrivastava: try opening `/dev/random` on a Linux or Mac system, then seek on that file. You won't be able to, because that file generates random data as you read from it. There is no 'beginning' to seek back to. So different iterators on that file object would give you entirely different data there.

Comment: @ShikharSrivastava: or create a [named pipe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Named_pipe) and open that in Python. You can read from such a pipe in Python, but you cannot read the same data from it again. Disk files are just one example of a file. They are simply not lists.